# Spring Boot: separate WS and MVC requests handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-ws

There is a Spring Boot application that combines WS and MVC. The problem for me is how to route WS-requests and MVC-requests to different dispatcher servlets. Here is a code snippet:

(not working):

```
@Configuration
public class WebServicesConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/*");
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
        SimpleUrlHandlerMapping handler = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
        handler.setDefaultHandler("mvc");

        return handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        DispatcherServlet ds = new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext());
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = servletContext.addServlet("mvc", ds);
        appServlet.addMapping("/dummy");
    }
}
```

WS uses `'/*'` mapping. MVC in this example uses `'/dummy'` mapping. The problem is that MVC-requests go to WS dispatcher servlet. I tried to use `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to route MVC-requests to MVC dispatcher servlet but it didn't help. Changing the mapping for WS is not allowed.

P.S. There was a mistake above. WS mapping is '/'

Comment: Map the `DispatcherServlet` to `/*` and the `MessageDispatcherServlet`to something like `/services/*`. Also `/dummy` means `/dummy` not `/dummy/123` etc those go to the WS one. If you use `/*` as the `DispatcherServlet` mapping you ca use the default spring boot configured one and only need to configure the `MessageDispatcherServlet`.

Comment: I m not trying to help you, but I really want to know why you didn't use different controllers ? a restController for WS and ordinary Controller for MVC ..

Comment: As I wrote, changing MessageDispatcherServlet mapping is not possible. I can only play with mvc mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found. I added the following exclusion into the bootstrapping class' annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class)
```

and changed WebServicesConfiguration class in the following way:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServicesConfiguration extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean mvcDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
        DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(context);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/dummy");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to ensure the mvcDispatcherServlet is called first in the case, to ensure that url requests to '/dummy' are checked before the '/' MessageDispatcherServlet consumes the request?